# How to set the background color of textblocks in a listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

My question is why the part `Textblock Background={Binding IsActive}` doesn't brush the textblock, but - when I am binding the Listbox background color to `IsActive` - the Listbox background is red. I just need to color each item in the Listbox where the `item.Activated` is `false`.

This is my code:

Xaml:

```
 <ListBox
  Grid.Row="1" 
  Background="{Binding IsActive}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding AllProjects}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}"
  Margin="0 5">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >
                <TextBlock Background="{Binding IsActive}">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                            <Binding Path="OrderName" />
                            <Binding Path="OrderNumber" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

MVVM:

```
private Brush _isactive;

public Brush IsActive
{
    get => _isactive;
    set
    {
        _isactive = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsActive");
    }
}

private void ColorBackground()
{
    foreach (var item in AllProjects)
    {
        if (item.Activated == false)
        {
            IsActive = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("Red");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're breaking the MVVM rules. Your view-model has a property of type `Brush`. That's wrong - this is a presentation aspect and should be handled by the view. Your viewmodel already has a property `bool Activated`. Your view should define a `DataTrigger` and set the background to needed colors according to that property value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why it's not working**

The `ListBox` is looking for the `IsActive` property in its `DataContext` object. And it seems to find it because your `ListBox` gets the right color.

However, each item generated in your `ListBox` (and all your `TextBlocks`) each have a different `DataContext` which doesn't seem to have an `IsActive` property.

**The dirty solution**

Move the `IsActive` property from the `ListBox` `DataContext` to each project `DataContext` (I assume you have a `ProjectViewModel` of some kind?). **Note that this is against MVVM** as the ViewModel should not know anythin about specific view details (like background color).

**The MVVM solution**

1. Either don't do any `Binding` and define your background colors as Resources and refer to them in your XAML using the `StaticResource` mark-up. This is much better as anything related to the view stays in the View, but this won't get your color to change based on your data. This would give a XAML like this:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="IsActiveBrush" Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="IsInactiveBrush" Color="Blue"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<!--...-->
<DataTemplate>
    <!--All your TextBlocks have the same color-->
    <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource IsInactiveBrush}">
        <TextBlock.Text>
        ...
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

2. The best option is to define a DataTemplate which automatically changes the background color based on the `Activated` boolean property like this, with a trigger:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <!--Default background of blue-->
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!--Change background to red when Activated is true-->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Activated}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
        <TextBlock.Text>
        ...
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

You would anyway remove any `Brush` reference from your ViewModel and keep only the boolean `Activated` property.

And if you combine options 2. and 3., you could replace the `Setters` with:

```xml
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource IsInactiveBrush}"></Setter>
...
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource IsActiveBrush}"></Setter>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation :)